# Lua: I know I have an extra end but where?

Tags: lua

This script was made for Roblox:

```
pastebin.com/raw/BGuvTx5q
```

Any idea where I would find the extra 'end' ?

EDIT: I don't think it's an extra end, but if someone could help me fix it, would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I fixed it! Heres the new code:

```
pastebin.com/raw/TJkCEd1T
```